# How to display init output to tty7 (or main tty)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-14.04, init.d, init

I have created my first init script in a linux server (ubuntu if that adds any information) that checks for an update, downloads it and executes it in each hour. The init file is as follows:

**/etc/init/updater.conf**

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

console output

respawn

script

    chvt 6
    chvt 7

    while true; do

        # code to check update ...

        if [ should_update ]; then

            # Download the script

            chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
            bash /path/to/script.sh
            rm /path/to/script.sh
        fi

        echo 'Rechecking for updates in 1h...'
        sleep 1h
    done

end script
```

The downloaded script starts as follows:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

exec > >(tee -i /var/log/update.log)
exec 2>&1

ScriptLoc=$(readlink -f "$0")

# check for root privilege
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo " This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   echo
   exit 1
fi

LOG_OUTPUT=/dev/tty4

(some_time_consuming_command 2>&1 > $LOG_OUTPUT) & spinner &!
```

The expected behavior is that after the installation of the linux finishes, the pressed will add the `updater.conf` to `/etc/init` which is done, then the linux reboots after the installation and shows the "Hello I will ..." message, then a spinner like this tuning `[-]` while redirecting the output of the `some_time_consuming_command` to TTY4

However, the current behavior is that the linux reboots in a black screen (TTY7) with nothing in it, when I switch to TTY1, I see the: "Hello I  will begin installation message". I did not understand this behavior.

Can anyone guide me for achieving the expected behavior?

EDIT: After reading a bit, I found that /dev/tty7 is in general the default because of the linked /dev/console in it. Am I right? Could anyone explain why TTY7 is the default one in general? And am I looking for displaying init output to /dev/console instead of /dev/tty7?